# Cannot convert from 'string[]' to 'string'

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, string

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(ofd.SelectedPath);
System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(files);
```

So, I get an error saying:

> Cannot convert from 'string[]' to 'string'

Is there any way I can Fix this?

Comment: string[] denotes an array, i think you need to identify the correct index before you can get the string method.

Comment: `GetFileNameWithoutExtension` takes a single filename. `GetFiles` returns an array (i.e. many).

Comment: You should consider editing your question and describing what are you trying to accomplish

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension?view=netframework-4.7.2)**  accepts one parameter - `string path`, which is the path of the file (and it is `string` not `string[]`).

In order to get all file names inside that directory, write something like this:

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(ofd.SelectedPath);
string[] fileNames = files.Select(f => System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f)).ToArray();
//or just
//string[] fileNames = files.Select(System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension).ToArray();
```

or simply iterate over files and get your file names (using `for`, `foreach` or any other loop you would prefer):

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(ofd.SelectedPath);

List<string> fileNames = new List<string>();
foreach(string file in files)
{
    fileNames.Add(System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file));
}
```

References: **[Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension?view=netframework-4.7.2)** , **[foreach, in (C# reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/foreach-in)**, **[Enumerable.Select Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netframework-4.7.2)**

Answer (score 2):

The `files` is an **array** of string and `GetFileNameWithoutExtension` accepts a parameter of type string. You need to iterate through files via `forach` or with LINQ, something like this:

```
var result = files.Select(System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension);
```

Or:

```
string[] result = files.Select(System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension).ToArray();
```

Just make sure that you have added the `using System.Linq;` to your `using` directives.

Comment: The Output of that comes up with " String[] "

Comment: Yeah, but `ofd` is very likely an `OpenFileDialog`, so is probably one element in the array.

Comment: @MatinPlays Yes. This will iterate through all files and will apply the  `GetFileNameWithoutExtension` to all of them as you wanted.

Comment: @MatinPlays You can also use `ToArray` in order to get the result as `string[]`. Have a look at my updated answer to know how.

Answer (score 1):

According to that [GetFileNameWithoutExtension function doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension?view=netframework-4.7.2) it requires a parameter of type `string` but you are passing a `string[]` to that method.

If you expect that array to contain only one element, you can call that function this way.

```
string fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(files[0]);
```

Comment: The output of that comes up with " System.String[] "

Comment: @Martin no it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

`System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(files)` expects a `string` not an array of strings (`string[]`).

If you want to remove the extension from all filenames in the `files` array you could use LINQ:

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(ofd.SelectedPath);
var filesWithoutExtension = files.Select(f => 
       System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f));
```